# What are differences in fetching xml values using attributes and indices in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml

In SQL server, for XML datatype, to fetch a value from the xml column I came across two types of format like

```
Select xml_column.value('(/Node1/Node1.1[1]/Text)[8]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from myTable
```

In this I have to change the query if any new Text node is added before this, e.g 8 to 9.

In another format to avoid this index dependency I have used

```
Select xml_column.value('(/Node1/Node1.1[@attributeX="val1"]/Text[@attributeY="val2"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from myTable
```

In terms of performance will it make any difference in the second query if I fetch large data?

Also, given that the attributes in the XML nodes are one to two sentences long.

Comment: If the element you want isn't always the 8th but can sometimes be the 9th then surely you should use the one that gives the correct answer? The xpath predicate approach (second one)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).